# How to stop Visual Studio Code from opening an external terminal window when I run my C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, terminal

I recently installed Visual Studio Code and when I run my C code, it will always open an external .exe window, when I would rather it just used the integrated terminal.

The extensions I have installed are:

C/C++ by Microsoft, C/C++ Extension Pack by Microsoft, C/C++ Themes by Microsoft, CMake by twxs, CMake Tools by twxs, Code Runner by Jun Han.

I also found an option within the settings of the Code Runner extension: "Code-runner: Run In Terminal". After ticking this option I can use the integrated terminal but Visual Studio first opens the external terminal which I have to close manually before I can actually use the integrated terminal.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: FYI, that external “.exe window” is known as “[terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator)”.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `launch.json` file to the `.vscode` to the folder where your project resides and configure it to do so. The relevant configuration for controlling the usage of an external console is provided below (for further information, refer to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_externalconsole)).

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            [...]
            "externalConsole": false,
            [...]
        }
    ]
}
```